# Ordinary LED response to nanosecond pulses

Tags: led, light, semiconductors, physics, step-response

Can anybody explain to me the output waveform generated on pins of an ordinary LED when it is exposed to very short light pulses?

I can clearly see that there is a precise difference in the length of the response by 55ns when the led is exposed to 110ns pulse instead of 55ns pulse. However the overall length of the waveform is much longer and there is a sharp pulse followed by a dip about 400ns later.

55ns light pulse response

[image]

110ns light pulse response

[image]

100us light pulse response

[image]

It seems that there is a rapid negative response first and then the expected voltage spike hundreds of nanoseconds later.

What are the mechanics of this?

Comment: hint for the future: most modern digital oscilloscopes have a screenshot function that can even save to a file. Also, when really having to take a photo of an oscilloscope screen (don't.), you should make sure to take it straight from the front, using e.g. a cardboard box as fixture for your camera or phone, so that pictures are directly comparable.

Comment: What are you plotting here, exactly? what kind of signal is that?

Comment: The vertical scale factor on the third shot is very different. The first two simply look like electrical noise that's getting coupled into your probe.

Comment: The plot is the output voltage on the led when exposed to 6000 lumen pulse of 55 and 110ns. The third shot is a much longer pulse so the led is allowed to respond more reasonably. The probe is connected to anode and cathode of the led which is placed in the light beam.

Comment: You can't measure the input pulse to an LED in lumens.  The current going in is most relevant (the voltage drop less so). You may have chosen a current that would be expected to cause emission of 6000 lumens but that's not the same thing in a real device.  A normal LED doesn't have an output voltage.  It has an electrical input and the output is light (+heat).  A circuit diagram showing what you're measuring would be a good idea - it's not clear whether you're measuring the forward voltage drop across the LED or the voltage across a series resistor to measure the current.

Comment: ... Your transient in the short pulse case is probably just an artefact of switching a fairly high current on suddenly, and with the settings (timebase and voltage scale) in your last figure you wouldn't see it anyway

Comment: What does the LED data sheet tell you about it working as a photo detector?

Comment: @ChrisH I think the OP is using the LED as a photodetector, not as a photoemitter. The 6000 lumens is coming from another source.

Comment: @ElliotAlderson that's another possibility.  I've had success with that rise times aren't great.  That makes it even more likely the peaks are switching transients picked up in the wiring

Comment: On all of these captures, are they being triggered from the emitter pulse circuit? Timing seems rather dubious. I'd run the pulse circuit from batteries, to avoid having any influence on the tests. And keep wiring away from LED to avoid EMI.

Comment: The light comes from a highly shielded source. The led is just connected across the scope probe and placed in the light beam. If I take a glass silicone signal diode like 1N4001 then I  get a similar pattern but the rise/fall times are shorter. I will try with a fast response photo diode as well to try to record "best case" and compare. What I want to understand is whether this has something to do with how a pn junction would typically respond when exposed to light or something else.

Comment: Sorry for the bad picture quality. I didn't think exact pixel precision matters here. What is interesting for me is the shape of the wave. If anyone has suggestions how I can rule out interference, let me know. It is difficult to completely shield the light source since the light source led has to be exposed through glass and cannot be placed behind a metal plate. Possibly a net though.

Comment: @Martin, show a schematic and how the circuit is implemented. In the ps time range, small parasitics in the traces and in the diode itself make a difference

Comment: The diode is hooked up directly to the scope probe using as short traces as possible. Basically ground to cathode and signal to anode. That's it.

Comment: Could it be, that first ring is your probe capacitance? Try different probes with the same LED and different LEDs using same probe.